# How can I send a POST request containing my form data from an excel file to my Extranet API?

Tags: excel, forms, http-post, winhttprequest

I'm a beginner in the technical aspect of Excel but I want to be able to receive my FB forms' Data from Facebook to my Excel File and then POST that Data into my EXTRANET using an API

I have the URL for the POST Request and the different IDs for every field

I want it to be able to send that Data automatically (maybe using cron?)

Please let me know if my idea is viable, as I said I'm only a beginner who wants to optimize his time

I read other threads with the (almost) same subject but couldn't really understand a thing or make use of it so please be patient with me